# How to prevent updated data in db to intervere with other tables?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm working on a php project to make a task schedule.

Companies have to sent a VAT declaration to the IRS each Vat-period. Some companies do this once a month and other companies do this once each quarter.

In my company table I use a vatperiod_id to determine how often the company has to sent a declaration. When I add a company the tasks will automatic be generated for the whole year. 
No problem so far. But sometimes the vat-period changes during a year.

Historic tasks which are saved in the db should not be modified, but only future tasks (which also have been generated by the script) should use the updated vat-period_id.

Example:
I add Company X with vatperiod_id 2 (declarations each quarter) and my script stores for month (4, 7, 10 and month 1 of the following year) a task. Now lets say the vatperiod_id
changes in July to vatperiod_id 3 (declarations each month). The tasks generated, for month 10 and 1 of the following year, should be deleted and replaced by a new task in each following month.

(It's quite difficult to explain)

How to solve this problem? Which data should I store in a db?

Comment: I really don't see the question here. You will of course need to delete the old tasks, but why is that hard? What have you tried and what were the results?

Comment: Maybe a better question is: Which data do I need to store in my company_table to be able to update the tasks.

Comment: Is the finest period-grain 1 month? Can their return be date (day)-based?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of generating future tasks/operations I now use a PHP function to verify which companies have to submit a VAT-declaration.

When I want to have an overview of companies that are obligated to submit a VAT-declaration in March (=example). I simply can check the company table for the companies where vatperiod_id=3 (companies that have to hand in VAT-declarations each month).

Only when an Tax-advisor "accepts" a task, the task will be stored in the database and the task-owner can alter the status.

```
function showVatOperations($month) {
    //declare variables
    global $mysqli;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `company` 
              JOIN `vat_period` ON company.vatperiod_id = vat_period.vatperiod_id
              JOIN `owner` ON company.owner_id = owner.owner_id
              WHERE company.vatperiod_id = 3";

    //check for each period which companies have to submit a declaration
    switch ($month) {
        case "1":
            $query.=" OR company.vatperiod_id = 2 OR company.vatperiod_id = 1";
            break;
        case "4":
            $query.=" OR company.vatperiod_id = 2";
            break;
        case "7":
            $query.=" OR company.vatperiod_id = 2";
            break;
        case "10":
            $query.=" OR company.vatperiod_id = 2";
            break;
    }

    //perform query to select company and vatoperation info
    $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die("ERROR $query. $mysqli->error()");

    showVatOperationDetails($result);

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt

- One row in the **Calendar** table is one day. The table is used to simplify handling of dates. Usually, you would pre-load this for the next 20 years, or so.
- The **Company** table also holds the current reporting period type (month, quarter, year..)
- **TaxSchedule** is pre-populated based on the `ReportingPeriodType`.  One option is to pre-populate this table with the finest grain (month) even if the company reports every quarter or year.
- One row in the **Declaration** table holds a return as submitted by a company.
- **Schedule_Declaration** is where declarations are matched against the schedule. One schedule can match several declarations (schedule = quarter, but declarations = monthly). One declaration can match several schedules (schedule = month, but declaration = quarter; late filing). Any matching is done on the application layer.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I will have a closer look at it. Some data you suggest to save is not needed for my project and that makes the db structure somewhat hard to understand. I'll try to simplify it to my needs and will let you know whether it solved my problems.